# Looking to create a 4x10 table that lists my array in velocity using a foreach loop

Tags: arrays, apache, foreach, velocity

I want to loop through an array listing [1-4] in the first row, [5-8] in the second and continue till the entire array is output.

```
#set ($cats = [
  "Accounting", "Admin & Clerical", "Automotive", "Banking", 
  "Broadcast - Journalism", "Business Development", "Construction", "Customer Service",
  "Design", "Distribution - Shipping", "Education - Teaching", "Facilities",
  "Finance", "General Business", "General Labor", "Government", 
  "Grocery", "Health Care", "Hotel - Hospitality", "Human Resources", 
  "Installation - Maint - Repair", "Inventory", "Legal Admin", "Management",
  "Manufacturing", "Marketing", "Nurse", "Pharmaceutical",
  "Purchasing - Procurement", "QA - Quality Control", "Real Estate", "Research",
  "Restaurant - Food Service", "Retail", "Sales", "Skilled Labor - Trades",
  "Strategy - Planning", "Supply Chain", "Transportation", "Warehouse"
] )
```

How do I grab the first 4 items in the array, place them into a row, and then move on to the next 4?

```
<table cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%!important;font-size:9px;font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;text-align:center;background:;color:black">
  #set ($counter = 0)
  #set ($j = )
  #foreach ($i in $cats)
    #if ( $counter % 2 == 0)
    <tr>
      <td>$i</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    #else
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    #end
  #end

</table>
```

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: My question is how do I grab the first 4 of the array and place them into a row then move on to the next 4

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Velocity at all, but based on my knowledge of other coding languages, try something like this and let me know how it goes.

```
<table cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="width:100%!important;font-size:9px;font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight:normal;text-align:center;color:black">
  <!-- The two sets in your code here looked superfluous --!>
  #foreach ($i in $cats)
    #if ( ( $foreach.index - 1 ) % 4 == 0)
      <tr>
    #end
    <td>$i</td>
    #if ( ( $foreach.index - 1 ) % 4 == 3 || $foreach.last)
      </tr>
    #end
  #end

</table>
```

**Edit:** After a quick search, I believe that Velocity foreach indexes will NOT be zero-based, so I have updated my code in consequence.  If that is incorrect, simply replace the two instances of `$foreach.index - 1` with `$foreach.index` (remove the `- 1`).